# Reloading JavaScript only

Tags: javascript

I am developing/testing some JavaScript functionality. Every change in the JavaScript code I make means I have to reload the page, and wait for Drupal to build the page from scratch, which I don't need at the moment.

Is there a way for telling the browser to reload that one file only?

Comment: i must say i am said about this being closed ... i wrote it while developing a drupal site.... it is closely related to problems that many drupal developers must face (any edit in javascript means waiting for the whole page to generate again ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is entering the following code into the console, where "xxx" is a part of the name of the script you want refreshed, and "yyy" its exact adress; the string after the question mark has to be changed each time to force Chrome not to cache it.

```
jQuery("[src*=xxx]").replaceWith('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yyy?m2fua6ijsufsds"></script>')
```

It could probably make for a nice useful mini module, which would provide a button/shortcut that would automate the call.

Comment: If this is a good answer to your question (so it actually does work), then please mark your own answer as accepted (with the tick)! Thanks!

Comment: i thought i would wait a while, so someone could come with a better idea :)

Comment: and does your own code work? I haven't tried it yet, but I'm curious.

Comment: yes, it works :)

Comment: If it really loads the renewed version of the script, then I think it's fine enough to accept your own answer. :)) You can also create `<script>` elements dynamically like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1199691/517705.

Comment: i wanted to be a good citizen :) but will only be allowed to accept my answer in 19 hours.